# Can I store int in longtext column and sum it?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

When save a post, I saved a "point" value in `post_content_filtered` column in `wp_posts table`. I didn't save it in `postmeta` table  because it's not easy to make sum in `postmeta`. Also, wordpress never use the `post_content_field` column for anything.  So, I think I'm making good use of it.
Now, when I need to sum the "points" for some posts, how to make mysql treat the points as `int` ?

Comment: `CAST(post_content_filtered AS SIGNED)`? http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cast-functions.html

Comment: Yeah, it works... but it is _horrible_ to abuse a longtext for this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understand the question but if you have a text field that you would like to treat as an signed integer something like this would work:

```
SELECT SUM(CAST(post_content_filtered AS SIGNED)) total FROM wp_posts;
```

I don't think the above will be necassary since mysql will use the field as a number depending on context, for example the following will return 6:

```
SELECT '1' + '10' - '5';
```

Read more about [mysql cast functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cast-functions.html)